# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified (using ffmpeg.probe())

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, probe

I'm trying to access metadata for a video using ffmpeg.probe() and it gives this error message. There is very little info on probe online.

```
import os
import ffmpeg


os.chdir('E:/F/Salvaged goods/Videos/Miro/Kvikmyndir/Blade_Runner_2049.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO')

pprint(ffmpeg.probe(filename='Blade_Runner_2049.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO.mkv', cmd='ffprobe'))
```

I have also tried this, and got the same error message:

```
pprint(ffmpeg.probe(filename='E:/F/Salvaged goods/Videos/Miro/Kvikmyndir/Blade_Runner_2049.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO/Blade_Runner_2049.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO.mkv', cmd='ffprobe'))
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hjalt\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\app_builder.py", line 50, in <module>
    pprint(ffmpeg.probe(filename='Blade_Runner_2049.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO.mkv', cmd='ffprobe'))
  File "C:\Users\hjalt\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_probe.py", line 20, in probe
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\hjalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\hjalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: `cmd='ffprobe'` ... do you have `ffprobe.exe` on Python's current working directory or on the system environmental path?

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means. Talk to me like I'm five lol

Comment: FFmpeg is an external program and the `ffmpeg-python` package that you are using in Python is only assisting you to call the command. Google "how to install ffmpeg" and make sure to put it on the system path.